# How to choose a method to perform a selector after a certain seconds?

Tags: ios

What is the difference among these three methods

```
1. sleep(5)
2. dispatch_after(<#dispatch_time_t when#>, <#dispatch_queue_t queue#>, <#^(void)block#>)
3. performSelector:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#> afterDelay:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>
```

In the second Method, how to choose the queue

Answer (score 3):

Method 1 will pause execution of the current method for 5 seconds, so the following code:

```
NSLog(@"Before sleep");
sleep(5)
NSLog(@"after sleep");
```

would have 5 second delay between the two logs.

Method 2 uses grand central dispatch (GCD) to schedule execution of a block of code on a specified queue.  This could be the main queue or a background queue - it is up to you to nominate a queue.  Execution of the current method will continue immediately with the code after the `dispatch_after`, so the following code:

```
NSLog(@"Before dispatch");
dispatch_after(5,dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{
    NSLog(@"in dispatch");
}
NSLog(@"after dispatch");
```

Would print

> Before dispatch
>
> after dispatch

and then 5 seconds later

> in dispatch

Method 3 would have the same result as method 2, except that it invokes a method (selector) on the current thread using runloop scheduling rather than a block and Grand Central Dispatch.

Method 2 is the most "modern" - using blocks and GCD.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sleep will lock the entire thread and wait for the amount of time to pass to continue. In general, this is a bad idea.
2. This is a good way to dispatch to a different thread, such as the main thread if you'll be updating UI. This one also makes more sense if there isn't a need for an entire function for the code to be executed.
3. This one is good if you've got a function that can occur on any thread. I personally prefer this method over the other two, even if you need to do work on a specific thread (you can dispatch within that method if necessary). It's cleaner and allows more testable and readable code.

As far as choosing queue, I recommend reading up on the [Grand Central Dispatch docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to accomplish.

1. The first method `sleep()`, blocks the current thread for the specified amount of time, and delays the execution of code.

The other two don't block the thread, as they schedule their actions.

2. The `dispatch_after` enqueues a block to be executed after a specified amount of time. After the time has passed it adds the block to the specified queue for execution.

   Example of using `dispatch_after` on the main thread

   > ```
   > dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(<#delayInSeconds#> * NSEC_PER_SEC)),
   > dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   >                 <#code to be executed after a specified delay#>
   >             });
   > ```

   instead of using the main thread (`dispatch_get_main_queue()`), you can also use `dispatch_get_global_queue` to get a background queue on which to execute the block without blocking the interface.
3. The `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:` method

   > registers with the runloop of its current context, and depends on that
   >   runloop being run on a regular basis to perform correctly.

   You can use it to schedule methods that require up to one argument, which you can pass along with the selector. It will perform the selector on the current thread.

   You can also cancel this request by using `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:`